# YouTube API Video Upload (videos:insert) query quota exceeded by uploading two videos only

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube API V3 to upload videos to my channel. I get access token through the playground and somehow I have really high numbers of queries per day:

These are my queries per day over the last week:

5070 3261 1656 9885 3312 6573 1656 17767

As you see, I managed to exceed 10k quota limit per day. How it is possible though? My videos have 10-minute average duration and 500MB average size.

Does uploading a video through videos:insert counts more than 2000 query points?

I'm using the Python example from official documents:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like uploading a video and setting up a custom thumbnail costs exactly 1656 quota points.

Also, trying to upload even if it returns an error still counts as a quota.

Answer (score 0):

Your link says:
"Quota impact: A call to this method has a quota cost of 1600 units in addition to the costs of the specified resource parts."

[Google / YouTube on Quota points](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) further says: "A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units."

So, I think about 2000 quota points per video upload sounds right.

Comment: I see but I did not upload more than 2 videos today because I got an error through the process while invoking the video upload method. Does that mean even if the upload does not succeed, quota is increased because I invoked the video:insert?